# How can I get an input value in a URL?

Tags: php, html, url

I'm trying to get the input value in a URL but the method I use is not working.

```html
<form action="" method="get">
  <input name="parrinName" type="text" />
</form>
<center>
  <a target="_blank" href="index.php?page=impression/lettre_carte_cadeau&IDClient=<?php echo $_GET['id'], $_GET['parrinName']; ?>&print&output=pdf">
      <img src="<?=IMAGES_URL?>fleche.jpg" border="0" align="middle"> Imprimer lettre carte cadeau</a>
</center>
```

How can I get the input value from the URL?

Comment: You forgot the dollar sign ($) & _GET : <?=$_GET['IMAGES_URL'] ?>

Comment: You need to submit the form to this url. <a> will not work

Comment: the question is how can i get the value of parrinName in the url.

Comment: 1. Add input type submit in your form. 2. Get your `parrinName` in PHP such as `$parrinName = $_GET['parrinName']`. 3. Use it anywhere you need.

Answer (score 0):

YOu can not directly put your form value to the URL, SImple way is to submit your form using `GET` method.

Look at into following code and see what you understand and what you need, modify code accordingly. **(click the button, and see the URL)**

```
<form action="index.php" target="_blank" method="get">
    <input name="parrinName" type="text"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="impression/lettre_carte_cadeau" />
    <input type="hidden" name="output" value="pdf" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2"  />

    <button name="print" type="submit">
        <img src="<?=IMAGES_URL?>fleche.jpg" border="0" align="middle"> Imprimer lettre carte cadeau</a>
    </button>
</form>

<?php 
//TO get the form values
$name = $_GET['parrinName'];
$id = $_GET['id'];
$page = $_GET['page'];

//..................
//...................
//DO what ever you like
?>
```

When you press the button, you will get URL like this,
`index.php?parrinName=&page=impression%2Flettre_carte_cadeau&output=pdf&id=2&print=`
But Remember make hidden those field which you dont want to show and also proper server side validation.